# Inserting html comments with VSCode when language mode is set to handlebars

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening html files in VS Code and setting the language type to handlebars, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> inserts

`{{!--  --}}`

instead of:

`<!--  -->`

I understand that vscode is inserting a comment in handlebars syntax instead of html syntax, but is there a way to override this setting as a user preference?

#### Repro Steps

1. Open VSCode
2. Open any html file
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
4. Type `Change language mode`, press enter
5. Type `handlebars` press enter
6. Insert a comment into the html document using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>